# Script to update MSMQ storage path location

Tags: powershell, messaging, msmq

[image]

Want to update the location to D: to a different folder

Comment: Sounds like a neat project. Good luck!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What word and what didn't work? You'll probably get help with specific issues if you post an example, but it's unlikely anyone is going to write the code for you from scratch...